# rails 5 strong params updating record sets other columns to nil

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

For some reason, when I submit my form and update my user profile record, my user profile records have all the other columns updated to nil for some reason.

Lets say User.last.user_profile has an attribute "linkedin_url" and it is set to "www.yahoo.com". Once I submit the form, the User :phone number, and UserProfile :work_address, :work_zipcode gets updated, but the "linkedin_url" gets set to nil. IDK why!

```
class UserProfilesController < ApplicationController
 def update

  @user = User.last

  if @user.update(user_profile_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
        redirect_to user_profile_path(@user)
      }

      format.json {
        render :show, status: :ok, location: @preference 
      } 
    end
  end
 end

def user_profile_params
  params.require(:user).permit( :phone_number, user_profile_attributes: [:work_address, :work_zipcode])
end
```

form

```
= form_for @user, url: user_profile_path(@user), method: :put do |f|
 = f.fields_for :user_profile do |ff|
  = ff.label :work_address
  %br
  = ff.text_field :work_address
  %br
  = ff.label :work_zipcode
  %br
  = ff.text_field :work_zipcode
  %br
 = f.label :phone_number
 %br
 = f.text_field :phone_number
 %br
 = f.submit "Submit", class: "btn"
```

Comment: simply add the linkedin_url to accepted attributes, params.require(:user).permit( :phone_number, user_profile_attributes: [:work_address, :work_zipcode, :linkedin_url])

Answer (score 0):

```
def user_profile_params
  params.require(:user).permit(
    :phone_number, 
    user_profile_attributes: [:work_address, :work_zipcode] # ⇐ HERE
  )
end
```

In the method above you should explicitly list `:linkedin_url`:

```
def user_profile_params
  params.require(:user).permit(
    :phone_number, 
    user_profile_attributes: [:work_address, :work_zipcode, :linkedin_url]
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just solved my own problem, it was because i didn't whitelist :id in the strong parameters.